# TCP sendto (C++) fails on Linux but not OSX. Errno: EINVAL 22 Invalid argument

Tags: linux, macos, c++11, tcp, sendto

On the client side of my application, the following runs fine on OSX. But when compiled/run on Linux (Ubuntu 12 or Raspbian)    sendto()    always fails with a EINVAL/22/invalid argument. How do I run it on Linux?

```
std::vector<uint8_t> rawVect;
// rawVect.push_back()...a bunch of bytes

const uint8_t* sendBytes = &rawVect[0]; // or rawVect.data();  
size_t sendSize = rawVect.size();

if(sendSize > 0){

    long numBytes = sendto(control_fd, sendBytes, sendSize, 0, res->ai_addr, _res->ai_addrlen);
}
```

I suspect C++ 11 libraries and std::vectors on Linux. My makefile looks similar to this.

```
mac:  
g++ -std=c++0x myprogram.cpp 
# (w/ llvm libc++)

ubuntu:  
clang++-3.5 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ myprogram.cpp  
# couldn't use g++ 4.8 or prior because it didn't support std::vector::insert as I was using it elsewhere. 4.9 not avail for Ubuntu 12.  

pi:  
g++-4.9 -std=c++0x myprogram.cpp
```

Comment: [man 3 sendto](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sendto) says that `EINVAL` may be returned if "The `dest_len` argument is not a valid length for the address family", perhaps despite the fact that the address argument is ignored for connected-mode sockets. Given that you mention TCP in the title, I assume that `control_fd` is a connected-mode socket. Try simply using `send(control_fd, sendBytes, sendSize, 0)` or even `write(control_fd, sendBytes, SendSize)` instead.

Comment: What @Casey said.  If you pass more than 64KB -28 bytes to sendto, it should fail since you can't send that much into a UDP datagram.

Comment: Thanks @Casey. That was it. Not sure how I got to sendto in the first place. Much obliged. I'll give you an answer if you copy it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[man 3 `sendto`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sendto) says that `EINVAL` may be returned if "The `dest_len` argument is not a valid length for the address family", perhaps despite the fact that the address argument is ignored for connected-mode sockets. Given that you mention TCP in the title, I assume that `control_fd` is a connected-mode socket. Try simply using `send(control_fd, sendBytes, sendSize, 0)` or even `write(control_fd, sendBytes, SendSize)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough to go on.  Add print statements to reveal the values of all the parameters passed to sendto.  Then print out the relevant members of res->ai_addr after casting back to sockaddr_in.

One hypothesis.  The value of ai_addrlen should exactly equal `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` assuming ipv4. Or `sizeof(sockaddr_in6)` if the socket is ipv6.  Some operating systems are less forgiving if you pass in a value that's bigger than the actual size expected for that socket type.  Such would be the case with assigning the ai_addrlen to be `sizeof(sockaddr_storage)`.